# Cannot see output when return type of function changes while using vector

Tags: c++, function

Given the following function in C++:

PS. Carefully notice <= in the for loops as the size of vector is [a.size() + 1][b.size() + 1]

```
vector<int> lcs2(vector<int> &a, vector<int> &b) 
{
    vector<vector<int> >L(a.size() + 1 , vector<int>(b.size() + 1 , 0));
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= b.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                L[i][j] = 0;
            else if (a[i - 1] == b[i - 1])
                L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1] + 1;
            else
                L[i][j] = std::max(L[i-1][j], L[i][j-1]);
        }
    }

    int index = L[a.size()][b.size()];
    vector<int> lcs(index + 1);

    int i = a.size() , j = b.size();
    while (i > 0 && j > 0)
    {
        if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])
        {
            lcs[index-1] = a[i-1]; 
            i--; j--; index--; 
        }
        else if (L[i - 1][j] > L[i][j - 1])
            --i;
        else
            --j;
    }
    return lcs;
}
```

When I run the following commands in the main() function:

```
vector<int> lcs = lcs2(a , b);
std::cout << lcs.size() << std::endl;
```

I am able to get output on the console. But when I make the following changes to the code:

1. Change return type of lcs2 to int
2. return lcs.size() instead of just lcs
3. change lcs datatype in main() from vector to int
4. Change the value being output from lcs.size() to lcs

I am not able to get the desired output on my console. When I run the build task from VSCode, I get a message like `The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221226356`.

Please help me out with this.

PS. Before the return statement in lcs2(), if I add a statement to print the value of lcs.size() , that works fine as well.

Comment: Hello, I have initialized the size of L vector as [size + 1][size + 1] . It makes obvious sense to use <= then

Comment: @n.m. Even if I use <= before making those 4 changes, the code works fine as expected

Comment: Ahhh sorry. Small phone screen, didn't see the long lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a.size(); ++i)
```

and then you access `a[i]` in the loop.  When `i == a.size()`, that's out of bounds, so you get undefined behavior.

try using the `at` method instead (use `a.at(i)` instead of `a[i]` and similarly for every other index operation), and you'll get an exception rather than undefined behavior.

Comment: Hello, the size of L is [a.size() + 1][b.size() + 1] . I don't see how that is causing this issue. But I have mentioned in the question that only on changing those 4 things the code crashes. The lcs2 function in the question without those 4 modifications is working

Comment: The crashing unpredictably means you have undefined behavior somewhere.  When you have undefined behavior, it might crash or might appear to work, and switch between those behaviors with changes to related things.  Crashes that go away when you add prints is almost always due to out-of-bounds access to things on the stack; the prints cause the compiler to rearrange things on the stack.